# Why can't I remove my event listener?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have an issue with removeEventListener, it doesn't seem to work at all, I've seen some other questions on this site but I don't get it, can you help me?

```
displayImg() {
    console.log('img')
    for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
      var line = "l"+i;
      var position = 0;
      var addDivLine = document.createElement('div');
      addDivLine.className = 'line';
      addDivLine.id = line;
      document.getElementById('container').appendChild(addDivLine);
      for (var j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
        var block = "b"+j;
        var element = line+"-"+block;
        var addDivBlock = document.createElement('div');
        addDivBlock.className = 'block';
        addDivBlock.id = element;
        document.getElementById(line).appendChild(addDivBlock);
        memory.addEvent(element);
      };
    };

showImage(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        memory.clickedBlock++;
        var block = event.target.id;
        memory.removeEvent(block);
}


addEvent(id){
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', function(){memory.showImage(event)});
  },
  removeEvent(id){
    console.log("remove");
    document.getElementById(id).removeEventListener('click', function(){memory.showImage(event)});
  },
```

I am creating div elements then put an eventListener on them, I call the same function to remove the event, I use the same id, is there something that I forgot? I probably don't fully understand how it really works.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to specify the same function reference for the handler to be removed. Currently, you try to remove a handler that could not have been registered before since it is define at the time of the `removeEventListener` call. @connexo I fear [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) requires a reference to the desired handler to be removed.

Comment: That's dumb. So how do you remove all click listeners from an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this two lines:

```
.addEventListener('click', function() { memory.showImage(event) });
```

and

```
.removeEventListener('click', function() { memory.showImage(event) });
```

`function() { memory.showImage(event) }` are two *different* functions. You need to provide reference to the same function in both cases in order to bind/unbind listener. Save it so some variable and use in both places:

```
.addEventListener('click', memory.showImage);
.removeEventListener('click', memory.showImage);
```

For example using directly `memory.showImage` will work properly as it's the same function in both cases.

Comment: Oh alright that was easier than I thought hehe, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The function looks like the same but its reference would be different. So, define the function in a scope where it's available for both function and use the reference in both case.

```
var callback =  function(){memory.showImage(event)};

addEvent(id){
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', callback);
}

removeEvent(id){
   console.log("remove");
   document.getElementById(id).removeEventListener('click', callback);
}
```